# Symfony EasyAdmin 3 display relation table in parent details page

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

How to display simple OneToMany children relation table in EasyAdmin 3 Symfony parent details page?

I trying to display table(list) of children in new panel, and cant figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a template for the field

```
{# @var ea \EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Context\AdminContext #}
{# @var field \EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\FieldDto #}
{# @var entity \EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\EntityDto #}
{% if ea.crud.currentAction == 'detail' %}
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Some Field</th>
        <th>Some Other Field</th>
    </tr>
    {% for value in field.value %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{ value.someField }}</td>
          <td>{{ value.someOtherField }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
{% else %}
  <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ field.formattedValue }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

And then just add this template to it

```
yield CollectionField::new('children')
    ->setTemplatePath('admin/fields/children.html.twig')
    ;
```

Comment: Yeah IC there is no easier way of doing this, I was hoping there will be something like Laravel Nova has, with relationships.