# Easyadmin 4: How to display edit view related collection as a table

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I've two entities: A_ and B_, where B_ is a collection of the A_.

Now in EA edit view B_ collection displays as embedded object:

```
class A_CrudController extends AbstractCrudController {
    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable {
        ...
        yield CollectionField::new('b_', 'B_ Collection')
            ->useEntryCrudForm(B_CrudController::class)
            ->setEntryIsComplex();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but I'd like to have a table view this collection where each row is element of the collection.
How to do it?

I try to use method in [Symfony EasyAdmin 3 display relation table in parent details page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65156859/symfony-easyadmin-3-display-relation-table-in-parent-details-page)
but it doesn't work for me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you create a template for the field as in the answer for the question you referenced? Please add your attempt and explain why "it doesn't work for me", thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work for him because he's using EasyAdmin 4 the guide is for EasyAdmin 3. What other information do you need to be able to provide an answer?